# String to textbox casting

Tags: c#, string, casting, textbox

```
string data = "test";
TextBox tb = (TextBox)data;  // i want something like that in order to 
tb.Backcolor = color.black;  // do this line
```

Comment: You want to assign to the `TextBox.Text` property, not the `TextBox` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use TextBox.Text = "bla" instead of cast

Answer (score 1):

Providing that you call the code with a method of a `Form`, you want something like that:

```
  String data = "test";

  // creation of a new TextBox with Text assigned to data... 
  TextBox tb = new TextBox() {
    Parent = this, // <- text box is on the Form...
    Location = new Point(10, 10),
    Size = new Size(100, 20),
    Text = data, // <- TEXT of the TextBox is data
    BackColor = Color.Black,
    ForeColor = Color.White,
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String data = "test";
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.text = data;
```

You can assign string directly to the textbox's using text attribute.
Hope this helps.